# How to start Spyder in Linux Enthought Canopy

Tags: linux, spyder, enthought

I have installed Enthought Canopy v-2.1.6 and downloaded Spyder v-2.3.8-8 with the Canopy Package Manager.  There were no warning or error messages during the installation, but I can figure out how to start Spyder

Comment: Not programming related, try https://serverfault.com/ and-or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder 2.3.8 is not maintained anymore, so we can't help you about it, sorry.

Comment: (1) It is programming-related because Canopy provides a programming language (Python) and Spyder is a programming tool. (2) Which version of Python?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Windows 10, not Linux. But after reading this question I installed Spyder via the package manager and tried to run it. I ended up finding the "spyderlib" folder in the site-packages directory and pulled the file spyder.py into the editor. Running it launched Spyder.
I know it has been a while since the question was posted, but I hope this helps somebody.